# Join doesn't give correct result

Tags: mysql, sql

I am running the below query using join. But this join doesn't give the correct result

```
SELECT pr.start_date,pr.end_date, p.contribution_id 
FROM civicrm_membershipperiod pr 
INNER JOIN civicrm_membership_payment p ON pr.membership_id=p.membership_id
where p.membership_id=11
```

Both tables contains three records

```
mysql> select *  FROM `civicrm_membershipperiod` ;
+----+---------------+------------+------------+
| id | membership_id | start_date | end_date   |
+----+---------------+------------+------------+
|  1 |            11 | 2015-01-01 | 2015-12-31 |
|  2 |            11 | 2017-07-09 | 2018-07-08 |
|  3 |            11 | 2018-07-09 | 2019-07-08 |
+----+---------------+------------+------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
mysql> select *  FROM `civicrm_membership_payment` ;
+----+---------------+-----------------+
| id | membership_id | contribution_id |
+----+---------------+-----------------+
| 27 |            11 |              39 |
| 28 |            11 |              40 |
| 29 |            11 |              41 |
+----+---------------+-----------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

But result is nine records instead of three records.

```
mysql> SELECT pr.start_date,pr.end_date, p.contribution_id FROM civicrm_membershipperiod pr INNER JOIN civicrm_membership_payment p ON pr.membership_id=p.membership_id where p.membership_id=11;
+------------+------------+-----------------+
| start_date | end_date   | contribution_id |
+------------+------------+-----------------+
| 2015-01-01 | 2015-12-31 |              39 |
| 2015-01-01 | 2015-12-31 |              40 |
| 2015-01-01 | 2015-12-31 |              41 |
| 2017-07-09 | 2018-07-08 |              39 |
| 2017-07-09 | 2018-07-08 |              40 |
| 2017-07-09 | 2018-07-08 |              41 |
| 2018-07-09 | 2019-07-08 |              39 |
| 2018-07-09 | 2019-07-08 |              40 |
| 2018-07-09 | 2019-07-08 |              41 |
+------------+------------+-----------------+
9 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

I am not sure where the error is.

This is I want:

```
2015-01-01  2015-12-31  39
2017-07-09  2018-07-08  40
2018-07-09  2019-07-08  41
```

Comment: Most people here want formatted text, not images.

Comment: I will correct it

Comment: Images are great but posting the queries and their results as text is even greater.

Comment: @Marvin, surely that depends on what fields he/she is selecting.  If he/she is selecting the start date or end date then distinct is worthless in this situation.

Comment: What would be your expected result? So far you have nine unique combinations of `contribution_id` and `start_date/end_date`, so getting less than nine rows would be rather surprising.

Comment: 3 * 3 = 9 rows.

Comment: I agree with @Marvin.

Comment: I'm guessing you're expecting to see `2015-01-01/2015-12-31` matched only with `39` but there is no direct relation between `contribution_id` and `start_date/end_date`.

Comment: In the relational paradigm, the order of rows in a table is irrelevant, so how could your database know which `civicrm_membershipperiod` to pare with which `civicrm_membership_payment`? Hence, is does not assume anything and just gives you all combinations. That is called a cartesian product.

Comment: With that table data, what is the expected result? (Formatted text here too, please.)

Comment: My expected result `| 2015-01-01 | 2015-12-31|39 |`
`| 2017-07-09 | 2018-07-08 |40 |`
`| 2018-07-09 | 2019-07-08 |41 |`

Comment: All your data model says is that some dates are related to some ids. So how would the database know that `2015-01-01/2015-12-31` should be related to `39` specifically? You need to modify your data model and add this information.

Answer (score 0):

I would expect to see nine records in this case.  It is because there are three records with membership_id of 11 in the first table and three records of membership_id of 11 in the second table and 3*3=9 i.e. every row with membership_id of 11 in the first table is joining with every row with membership_id of 11 in the second table.

The problem here is that there is a many to many relationship between these two tables, so you need a junction.  However, do you actually need the: civicrm_membership_payment table? Can you just move contribution_id  from civicrm_membership_payment to civicrm_membershipperiod and then delete civicrm_membership_payment? Then just do:

```
select * from civicrm_membershipperiod
```

If you cannot do this, then I would look into Junction Tables for many to many relationships.

Comment: | 2015-01-01  2015-12-31               39 |
| 2017-07-09   2018-07-08               40 |
| 2018-07-09  2019-07-08               41 | This is I want

Comment: I have updated my question.  I have not tested it.  Let me know it works.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/16656508)

Comment: @Alberto, I have modified my answer.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The result is absolutely correct according to what you have written.
The membership_id of each tuple in both tables civicrm_membershipperiod and civicrm_membership_payment is 11.
As each tuple of civicrm_membershipperiod is matched against each tuple of the other table on the column membership_id, it finds no mismatches. Due to this, it yields 3*3=9 matches.

Answer (score 0):

This is the expected behaviour, given your data. You are `JOIN`ing your two tables using `membership_id`. However, each row in `civicrm_membership_payment` with `membership_id = 11` matches three records on the other table. Thats why you have 3 x 3 = 9 rows in your result.

This looks like a design flaw, your table `civicrm_membership_payment` should have a reference that allows it to decide *to which period this payment refers to*.

*dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.2&fiddle=5a97de561996abe5787e8fb2b602d808)* for your current situation.

---

**Alternative**: change the definition of your tables to account for that:

```
CREATE TABLE civicrm_membershipperiod
(
    /* no need for a synthetic id, surrogate primary key */
    membership_id INTEGER,
    start_date date,
    end_date date,
    PRIMARY KEY (membership_id, start_date),  /* "Natural" PK */
    CHECK (end_date >= start_date)
) ;

INSERT INTO civicrm_membershipperiod
    (membership_id, start_date, end_date)
VALUES
    (11, '2015-01-01', '2015-12-31'),
    (11, '2017-07-09', '2018-07-08'),
    (11, '2018-07-09', '2019-07-08') ; 

CREATE TABLE civicrm_membership_payment
(
    contribution_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,  /* Surrogate key, not really necessary */
    membership_id   INTEGER NOT NULL,
    start_date      date NOT NULL,

    CONSTRAINT fk_civicrm_membershipperiod_civicrm_membershipperiod 
        FOREIGN KEY (membership_id, start_date)
        REFERENCES civicrm_membershipperiod(membership_id, start_date)
) ;

INSERT INTO civicrm_membership_payment
    (membership_id, contribution_id, start_date)
VALUES
    (11, 39, '2015-01-01'),
    (11, 40, '2017-07-09'),
    (11, 41, '2018-07-09') ;

SELECT 
    pr.start_date,pr.end_date, p.contribution_id 
FROM 
    civicrm_membershipperiod pr 
    INNER JOIN civicrm_membership_payment p 
        ON p.membership_id = pr.membership_id AND p.start_date = pr.start_date
WHERE 
    p.membership_id=11
```

```
start_date | end_date   | contribution_id
:--------- | :--------- | --------------:
2015-01-01 | 2015-12-31 |              39
2017-07-09 | 2018-07-08 |              40
2018-07-09 | 2019-07-08 |              41
```

*dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.2&fiddle=d8316cb222df0b06994cffb78c12718e)*

---

**NOTE**: You *don't need* to have an `AUTO_INCREMENT` id for every table. They might be convenient in some occasions, but you can also use *natural primary keys* (a column or combination of columns that will let you uniquely identify rows in your table, and that has some *meaning*). I've used them instead of the synthetic PK where I thought they would better represent the problem at hand.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying and your answer. I have to change the table design

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned in my remark, by default, SQL does not consider the order of rows in a database relevant, so it can not match the first row of one table to the first row of another and so forth.

For decades, people have accepted that, but recently sql is extended with new statements that resolve this issue. Unfortunatly, this has not been standardised, so it lead to further divergion of SQL dialects. For T-SQL, see this documentation on [row_number()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/row-number-transact-sql) and [rank()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/rank-transact-sql)

### The sollution is to add row numbers first, before joining:

```
SELECT pr.start_date,pr.end_date, p.contribution_id 
FROM (select *, ROW_NUMBER() 
                OVER(PARTITION BY membership_id 
                ORDER BY start_date ASC) as row_nr
      from civicrm_membershipperiod ) pr 
INNER JOIN (select *, ROW_NUMBER() 
                OVER(PARTITION BY membership_id 
                ORDER BY contribution_id ASC) as row_nr
      from civicrm_membership_payment ) p 
ON pr.membership_id=p.membership_id and pr.row_nr = p.row_nr
where p.membership_id=11
```

Comment: can you provide your answer for mysql